# Bijective continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Can anyone check whether my proof is correct?

Suppose there does exist continuous bijective map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

And consider 3 connected curves $C_{i}$ $(i=1,2,3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that all three intersect at only one point $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Since $f$ is continuous, we have $f(C_{j})=I_{j}$ for $j=1,2,3$, with each $I_j$ being closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since $f$ is bijective and all three curves intersects exactly at one point $p$,we have $\bigcap I_{j}=\{ f(p) \} $singleton set in $\mathbb{R}$ which isn't possible.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: (1) To say that $I_j$ is closed, you need to assume that your curves are closed. (2)To conclude, you need to mention that your intervals are not reduced to a point (3)Using two curves is enough! (4) Set apart those details, it seems correct.

Comment: It may be easier to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$ is connected while $\mathbb{R}-\{a\}$ is not

Comment: @Gaussian How is using two curves enough?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: thanks for correcting my comment. If the OP takes closed curves, then he indeed needs to take three curves. I actually had in mind a specific case: the one of two open segments of the plane, intersecting at exactly one point, for which the same argument works.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to note that for any $p \in \Bbb R^n$, $n \ge 2$, $\Bbb R^n \setminus \{p\}$ is connected, while for injective $f$:

$$f[\Bbb R^n \setminus \{p\}] = \Bbb R\setminus \{f(p)\}$$

is not connected whatever $f(p)$ may be, contradicting the continuity of $f$, which preserves connectedness.

Your idea does work, but for a full proof you have to fully define them (i.e. give formulae for them, e.g.) and then use injectivity to show $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 = \{f(p)\}$ plus that you just *claim* that this is impossible for $\Bbb R$, but don't give an argument for it. So your attempt is too sketchy (for most teachers grading it, e.g.) while the first idea is more general (works for many spaces) and easier (only need simple facts on connectedness).

Comment: As someone who actually grades this sort of stuff, I would be happy to give points for the proof OP gave. Giving formulas for the curve is absolutely pointless. The missing points (checking that the triple intersection is still a point and that three nontrivial intervals cannot intersect pairwise at only just a point) are very elementary. If the students are at a level where this sort of thing is routine, giving a full proof is just tedious. And above all, it's always nice to read an unusual proof like this. I think this is the first time I actually see this one.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I'm happy I don't have grade tests any more.  I would like a proof for the impossibility of the situation in the reals, though, the first two are minor (probably they would draw a picture to illustrate), but here this would be a first year college assignment and maturity levels can vary wildly there.